# How find a SubForm of a application with changing texts?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have Application X with Subform x1, x2, x3.

The Subform has, because its multi-language, not a static text in it, neither a specific window header text or something.

What can I do to find this window in my code an react when its open, e.g. with a messagebox?

Comment: Could you provide more details on your problem? From your question I only can guess what technologies are you using and what do you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use it's [name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.name%28VS.80%29.aspx) to find it.

F.e.

```
    public bool FindWindow(string windowName)
    {
        foreach (Form childWindow in this.MDIChildren)
        {
            if (childWindow.Name == windowName)
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the window you're looking for is in another application, you have to find out its window name (or window class). You can use Spy++ for this, which is installed with Visual Studio and/or the Windows SDK (not sure). You can also try UISpy, which uses Windows UI Automation and is also installed with one of them. Once you know the name, you can use the Win32 API function `FindWindow(Ex)` to find the window, or use Windows UI Automation (from the `System.Windows.Automation` namespace).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure creating several forms for localization is a good thing. Do you know about Localization?